# Plotting ROC curve for binary image

Tags: roc

I think ROC has some limitation to evaluate the performance of some binary classifier. I plot the ROC for an image classifier with this instruction: first I apply my detection method to the image, it's result is a gray-scale image. Now I must apply different threshold to obtain different binary images. For a range of threshold (for example th=0.01:0.01:1), I obtain a binary image corresponding to each threshold. Then for each binary image, true positive rate(TPR) and false positive rate(FPR) are calculated which (TPR,FPR) determines a point on the ROC curve. The whole curve includes the points that are calculated for each binary image. 
**And my problem: if at the first step I have a binary image against a gray-scale image, how I can apply different threshold to it for plotting ROC. Is there any performance evaluation instead of ROC that be suitable for this state?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This is a statement, not a question. Please write a question if you want an answer.